# Чат-бот + БД + панель управления (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, база-данных

Хочу создать квиз бота, который будет задавать вопросы из БД + возможность пополнять БД вопросами и ответами на них (для этого хочу создать своего рода панель управления в web)

**Как вы поняли, проект будет состоять из следующего:**

- Чат-бот ICQ New (с этим всё понятно)
- БД (Как хранить некоторые вопросы в видео картинки, причём так, чтобы бот мог использовать их в дальнейшем)
- Панель-управления (самая сложная и непонятная для меня часть, как связать её с БД)

**Я хотел бы чтобы вы помогли мне со следующими вопросами:**

- Какую БД лучше всего использовать?
- Какие библиотеки Python мне
  понадобятся?
- Как создать эту саму "панель управления" и "соединить"
  её с БД?

Comment: чат-бот где будет? Мессенджер\социальная сеть\сервис?

Comment: @D.Violet  пытался избежать этого вопроса - ICQ New (мессенджер)...

Answer (score 2):

я бы взял `sqlite3` в качестве БД, для разработки и тестов:

- Файловая структура - вся база данных состоит из одного файла, поэтому её очень легко переносить на разные машины. [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)
- Используемые стандарты - хотя может показаться, что эта СУБД примитивная, но она использует SQL. Некоторые особенности опущены, но основные все-таки поддерживаются.
- Отличная при разработке и тестировании - в процессе разработки приложений часто появляется необходимость масштабирования. SQLite предлагает всё что необходимо для этих целей, так как состоит всего из одного файла и библиотеки написанной на языке C.

[SB Admin2](https://startbootstrap.com/themes/sb-admin-2/) в качестве панели управления (`bootstrap`).

ну и `Flask` - фреймворк для создания минималистичных каркасов веб-приложений, сознательно предоставляющих лишь самые базовые возможности.

минимальный пример как отобразить данные из БД в панели управления через Flask:

`.py`:

```
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM dataset")
data = cur.fetchall()
render_template('template.html', data=data)
```

`.html`:

```
{% for item in data %}
<tr>
    <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
    <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
    ...
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Не подскажите, как реализовать добавление и удаление элементов БД через эту панель управления? (Предположим мне в одну из таблиц с вопросами нужно добавить ещё один вопрос)
Я не прошу от вас конкретного примера или код (это конечно бы не было лишним), мне достаточно принципа и общего хода мысли, для того чтобы понять как это работает.

Comment: напишите свой ник в телеграм